# Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url'

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, localhost

I started my new Spring Boot Application, but I faced the following problem when I try to run it:

> localhost 8080 already in use

Before that I had an old eeproject and I decide to delete it and try to delete tomcat properties there. After I try to rerun my Spring Project, when I start to run it:

> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class.

What shall i do?

My Main Class:

```
package com.example.sweater;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->

</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>serving-web-content</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>serving-web-content</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Comment: Please update the question with application.properties and main class

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by applcation.properties? It's very fresh project and i only added maven dependencies

Comment: Please update the question with your pom.xml

Comment: I update it as you ask, i hope that will help to figuare out what is the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove following dependency from pom file.

```xml
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Spring-Boot automatically tries to find a datasource if it finds `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependencies on classpath.

Comment: Thank you very much, i did not notice that, i forgot that i add jpa dependencie and also forgot to add my postgresql dependencie, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your terminal and run `sudo lsof -i tcp:8080` to get the PID and then kill the process using `kill -9 xxxxx` where "xxxxx" is your PID and now you can restart your application at port 8080.
   For windows, type `netstat -aon | find "8080"` and kill the process using `taskkill /F /PID xxxxx` where "xxxxx" is your PID.
2. If you have not added an SQL dependency, add an SQL dependency first (eg  MySQL or PostgreSQL) then in your resources->application.properties add your SQL properties.
   If you are not planning to use a database, remove the Spring JPA dependency.

Comment: i did it, thank you, but after that i faced to a new problem 
> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Comment: If you have not added an SQL dependency, add an SQL dependency first (like MySQL or PostgreSQL) then in your resources->application.properties add your SQL properties

Comment: If you are not planning to use a database, remove the Spring JPA dependency.